# Timestamp column in sql to valid string representation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table with Column data type "timestamp" in sql server.

Currently I am trying to get the data from this table to sqlite database. as it needs only string value. So far i have not been able to find correct way to convert to string.

So for example my SQL Value is 0x0000000000012DE0

When I get the record using entity framework, I get byte array.

Tried to convert using following code to string.

```
value = BitConverter.ToInt64(Version, 0);
```

However for same record, i get 0xE02D010000000000

This is one difference.

The second, Since I am working on azure mobile app, and this data also goes to android via WebAPI controller.The result I get from fiddler is something in this format

AAAAAAABM8s=

I want to also convert the byte arrray value in above format .

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is none. `timestamp` is the obsolete name of the [`rowversion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) type, a binary value used for optimistic concurrency that has no specific meaning. There is no string representation because you *can't* use it  in queries. Its value is updated by the database every time a row changes. The only guarantee you have is that will increase if the row is modified

Comment: *Why* do you want to extract the rowversion value in the first place?

Comment: because I am putting the same data in sqlite database in android for prepackaging purpose. and currently from webapi(via entity framework) it fills it with value like AAAAAAABM8s=

so I want to also get the value in same format in my code which will eventually match.

Comment: As I already mentioned, and the docs show, the value doesn't have any meaning outside the database. It *is* 8 bytes long and could be treated as a 64-bit integer. Any modification to the row though will change that value.

Comment: thanks, but then AAAAAAABM8s= this format ? can I convert it to this one?

Comment: You can convert to whatever you want. That looks like Base64. Why use *that* though, instead of a 64-bit integer?

Comment: that's interesting part. azure mobile app uses this and gives similar value to android , which I have no control over at this moment of time. the "EntityData" class has the c# representation of SQL column and hence I am forced to match the same.

Comment: @MandarJogalekar, there's a lot of tricks to getting your timestamp data right. You have to get your endianness right (this accounts for your discrepancy between your SQL array and the EF array - reverse the EF array before converting, and you'll get the expected result). You also have to get your most basic storage unit right - it's not actually `Int64` that you want - for the purpose of all your comparisons it's `UInt64`, because timestamps have no sign. Using `Int64` leads to weirdness such as `long.MaxValue + 1 < long.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my ASP.NET Core, EF Core 2.0, Angular 2 app. This was a database first development and changing the database definition was not within my remit.

In my case, EF Core automatically performed the concurrency check for me where the Timestamp column was present in the table. This was not an issue for updates because I could pass the DTO in the body but with deletes I could not.

To pass the timestamp I used a query string. The value being the Base64 string representation of the timestamp e.g. AAAAAAACIvw=

In my repository layer I convert the string back to a byte array e.g.

```
   byte[] ts = Convert.FromBase64String(timestampAsBase64String);
```

Then delete using the create and attach pattern (thereby eliminating any chance of lost updates)

```
   ModelClass modelobj = new ModelClass { Id = id, Timestamp = ts};
   _dbcontext.Entry(modelObj).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

Thanks to this thread and the CodeProject article [Converting Hexadecimal String to/from Byte Array in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4086/Converting-Hexadecimal-String-to-from-Byte-Array-i) to get this resolved.